# How can i find out the date a node was registered with chef server?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to find out the date a node was registered with chef server. Is it possible to find this info using the Chef API's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such information in ohai automatic attributes.

Here is the list: https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#automatic-ohai

The closes information is `ohai_time` - you can check there which is the time Ohai was last run.